# How can I make a QT app displaying very large amount of data with low memory usage?

Tags: qt, procmon

(it's a Sysinternal's-Process-Monitor-like system monitor program based on QT 5.7.0 which could monitor and record most behaviors of process in the system.

**program view**

[image]

**memory usage**

[image]

As you can see it cost 100MB+ memory when there are 30000+ events recorded.
and the memory usage could be easily increased to 1.0GB, even 2.0GB when there are more events, that's unacceptable in low performance machine. shall I save these events in sql database?

I use a QTableView with a custom model inherit from QAbstractTableModel attached to it, which displays only visible items. the memory issue is not caused by UI, since it cost so much memory even if I remove the tableview.

Comment: But you even didn't say which classes, widgets and technologies do you use

Comment: Will that low performance machine be able to save all the events in a conventional database without slowing everything even further?